# Does disabling support for exceptions also disable support for `std::move_if_noexcept`?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, move-semantics

Some shops (e.g., some video game development teams) disable support for exceptions in their build environment. With exceptions disabled, developers would have no reason to declare their move operations `noexcept` (assuming that such code would even compile). But standard library implementations are supposed to call `std::move_if_noexcept` when implementing some operations (e.g., `std::vector::push_back`). Do standard library implementations typically check during compilation to see if exceptions are disabled and, if so, use `std::move` instead of `std::move_if_noexcept`? Do compilers cause `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible` to return true for all types when exceptions are disabled? Or does disabling support for exceptions have the unexpected side effect of having `std:move_if_noexcept` fail to enable move operations?

I'm interested in what happens in practice. I understand that disabling support for exceptions takes us out of the realm of the C++ standard.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easy to test for yourself?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I could certainly test it for myself for the compilers I have access to, but the number of compilers I have access to is limited, and I thought people working in environments where exceptions are routinely disabled would already know the answer. As to whether it'd be "easy" to test...there'd be some scouring of standard library implementations required to find out what was going on, and that's not always simple work.

Comment: Neither libc++ nor libstdc++ seem to be interested in whether the compiler disables exceptions, so you won't magically have all moves be nothrowing moves in those libraries. The traits like `std::is_nothrow_constructible` are expressed in terms of the `noexcept` operator, which is generally unrelated to whether exceptions are actually supported by the environment. It's just an abstract part of a function declaration as far as the trait is concerned.

Comment: Although it doesn't appear to be the case, it certainly seems like compilers should implicitly make everything "noexcept" whenever exceptions are disabled. This should be a very simple fix for most compiler vendors to implement. You should let GCC and Clang people know about this, if it's not already on their to-do list.

Answer (score 4):

This code outputs `false true false true` on both GCC 4.9 and clang 3.5 with or without exceptions enabled:

```
void foo() {}
void bar() noexcept {}
void foo2() noexcept(noexcept(foo())) {}
void bar2() noexcept(noexcept(bar())) {}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << noexcept(foo()) << ' ' << noexcept(bar())
        << ' ' << noexcept(foo2()) << ' ' << noexcept(bar2()) << std::endl;    
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/901a621c5fa627cc)

So it looks like `noexcept` behavior doesn't depend on compiler options at least for these two compilers.

Update: VS2013 [doesn't support `noexcept` at all](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> -fnothrow-opt 
>   Treat a throw() exception specification as if it were a noexcept specification to reduce or eliminate the text size overhead
>   relative to a function with no exception specification. If the
>   function has local variables of types with non-trivial destructors,
>   the exception specification actually makes the function smaller
>   because the EH cleanups for those variables can be optimized away. The
>   semantic effect is that an exception thrown out of a function with
>   such an exception specification results in a call to terminate rather
>   than unexpected.

So according to the gcc documentation throw functions become noexcept specifications.

This should mean more objects will return true not less

Comment: This is the documentation for a different option than what the OP is asking about. Enabling or disabling exception support is done with `-fexceptions` / `-fno-exceptions`.